# Laravel 5.4, Login page keep redirecting

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having an issue where a login page keeps redirecting me back to login instead of going to the HomePage.

My Routes file:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return redirect()->route('dash');
    });

    Route::get('dash', 'DashController@index')->name('dash');
});

Route::get('login', ['as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'LDAPAuthController@index']);
Route::post('login', 'LDAPAuthController@login');
```

Everything else is set to its normal default setting:

RedirectIfAuthenticated Middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/home');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

My login controller:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Services\CakePHPHash;
use App\Users;
use Redirect;
use Auth;
use View;


class LDAPAuthController extends Controller {



  public function login(Request $request) {

    $user = Users::where('email', strtolower($request->email))->first();
    $hash = new CakePHPHash;


    if(($hash->hash($request->password, null, true)) !== $user->password) {
      return back()->with('error', 'Username and/or password are incorrect.');
    }

    Auth::login($user);

    return Redirect::to('/');

  }

   public function logout() {
      Auth::logout();
      Session::flush();
      return back()->with('error', 'You just logged out.');
   }

  public function index(Request $request) {
    return View::make('auth.login');
  }

}
```

My Sample Dash Controller:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use \App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Auth;


class DashController extends Controller {


public function index() {


      return view('Home.home');
  }


}
```

I simplified my Users model down to just changing primary and table name:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Session;
use Auth;

class Users extends Authenticatable
{

  protected $table = 'users';

  protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';


public function getRememberToken()
  {
    return null; // not supported
  }

  public function setRememberToken($value)
  {
    // not supported
  }

  public function getRememberTokenName()
  {
    return null; // not supported
  }

  /**
   * Overrides the method to ignore the remember token.
   */
  public function setAttribute($key, $value)
  {
    $isRememberTokenAttribute = $key == $this->getRememberTokenName();
    if (!$isRememberTokenAttribute)
    {
      parent::setAttribute($key, $value);
    }
  }
}
```

This isn't the first I'll be making an App in Laravel, but this is giving me headaches unlike before. Another piece of info I'm concerned about is that the $user gives out the right user and user_id, but the login_web_ session is giving out a different one (not the right user_id) from debugbar. Auth::check() returns true though.

Comment: if its redirecting then it should show you the errors

Comment: Please, attach your whole route file.

Comment: Are you getting an error on each redirection `Username and/or password are incorrect.`